# How to get balance of a token in 1 line of code on Ubuntu

Tags: balances

To get the balance of ether in an address, I am using the code below. (1 line)

```
sudo geth --exec \
  "web3.eth.getBalance('0xf6e5911696a3729a7740cbdcd64c05bc2eec60e7')" attach
```

I get: `165060000000000000`

I need to get balance of token (e.g. Golem) in one line like above. Can not interact with console. Return can be anything, 1 line or JSON.

Also looking for 1 line to send token like below:

```
sudo geth --exec \
  "eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', \
  to: '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', value: '10000000000000000', \
  gas: '0x76D0', gasPrice: '0x4A817C800'})" attach
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tokens that adhere to the ERC20 standard (which the [Golem token](https://etherscan.io/token/Golem) is), to get the token balance for a given address, you need to execute the method on the token contract called `balanceOf(address)`.

You don't need to send this as a real transaction into the Ethereum blockchain, since your local node (if it's fully-synced) already has this data, and that function is a read-only method (doesn't change the state of the smart contract). So the command you want is `eth.call()`, not `eth.sendTransaction`:

```
sudo geth --exec \
  "eth.call({to: "0xNNNNN", data: "0xNNNN"})" attach
```

Specifically, for the Golem contract, the "to" is `0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d`, and to generate the "data" variable, for this specific contract interaction, it's going to be a 32-byte hex string, in two 16-byte pieces. The first piece is the function selector for the `balanceOf(address)` function (`0x70a08231000000000000000000000000`), and the second half is the address you want to look up. So, for that example address you gave:

```
sudo geth --exec \
  "eth.call({to: "0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d", \
  data: "0x70a08231000000000000000000000000f6e5911696a3729a7740cbdcd64c05bc2eec60e7"})" attach
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an example for sending token like you did for the balanceOf(address) above. How should I format the data string. for sending 1 ETH I would use sudo geth --exec "eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xf6e5911696a3729a7740cbdcd64c05bc2eec60e7', to: '0xDF1b0d8c6B3BCc4cdfc6E8A710C02a265bC5d25d',value: '100000000000000000', gas: '0x76D0', gasPrice: '0x4A817C800'})" attach

Comment: To do the same thing for sending tokens, in the ERC20 standard, that's the `transfer(address _to, address _from)` method. Its function selector is `0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000` and then needs two addresses after it, so you'll end up with a `data` element that's 48-bytes long.

Comment: How about the amount??? Is the call function read only, because this doesn't work sudo geth --exec "eth.call({to: '0xad408ef944da873fe9b65f4e78e21ac2d489db90', value: '100000000000000', gas: '0x76D0', gasPrice: '0x4A817C800', data: '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000280e5dbe0d36be7344743ce03‌​4b104b94d930e51df1b0‌​d8c6b3bcc4cdfc6e8a71‌​0c02a265bc5d25d'})" attach then I get "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000‌​0000000"

Comment: No, the transfer function is not read only (you're sending tokens to someone else), so needs to be `eth.sendTransaction`

Comment: How/where to input value, gas, gasPrice. . Example of sending string would be nice.

Comment: You have an example of that in your original question; `gas` and `gasPrice` are additional properties in the JSON blob, alongside `to` and `data`.

Comment: is there any spec on how to assemble the `data` variable? where did you get those values from?

Comment: @Nulik, that would be best submitted as a separate question; I can answer it, but it's more involved, so wouldn't be best in a comment.